# Android Studio Gradle: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts / JCenter is at end of life

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

In Android Studio 4.2 there is a warning:

[image]

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

If I remove `jcenter()` then it can't find some dependencies of my app project:

```
   > Could not find org.koin:koin-core:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:8.1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

In replace of `jcenter()` I added `mavenCentral()`

Comment: I guess you need to check the homepages of the different missing JARs to see where you might get them in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For koin, change the group id from `org.koin` to `io.insert-koin` - the latter is published on maven central.

For chartboost, you can use the following repo:

```
maven {
    url "https://dl.bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/"
}
```

Also note that there are newer versions such as koin 2.2.2 / 3.0.1 and chartboost 8.2.0.0. Older versions are likely not republished in non-jcenter repos.

[mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) is a good service for locating packages.

Answer (score 64):

Move `mavenCentral()` above `jcenter()`.

do a clean/build on your project.

comment out `jcenter()`

By moving `mavenCentral()` above `jcenter()`, `mavenCentral()` now becomes the primary repository for all non Google artifacts. By doing a clean and build, all artifacts are now moved to `mavenCentral()`.

I had to look this up and tried it. I went from all heck breaking loose after I removed `jcenter()` to being able to build my final project for school again.

Comment: FYI - As of 2021-06-22, mine had mavenCentral() above jcenter() but now it warns you that you have to remove it. I removed jcenter() and rebuilt and all is well now.

Comment: After commenting ``jcenter`` clean the project.

Answer (score 5):

Locate all `build.gradle` files in your project folder tree, open them and replace `jcenter()` by `mavenCentral()`. It works for me most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

just commenting out jcenter() will help,
mavencentral() is already above jcenter.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting that the AndroidStudio project template still adds the ref to jcenter() to gradle, but then as soon as the project attempts to build it requests that you remove it.

I just delete it from the gradle file and then it works.

[image: remove jcenter()]

Answer (score 2):

So there are two issues here.

1. First, we need to move MavenCentral above jCenter in all projects
2. Second, Android build tools version need to upgraded to 4.2.0 and above. As Android internal build tool dependencies are going to jCenter

   dependencies {
   classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
   }

It should work

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help**

1. Go to **App/Gradle Scripts/build.gradle** *(Project:---)*
2. Change the `jcenter()` on build script{} and in all project repositories.
3. and Sync now.

This is how it looklike before.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and after.

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavencentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavencentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone.

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            ...
        }
    }
```

I used this to resolve:

```
> Could not find com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.26.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, while i was using the Android Studio `Artic Fox Beta - 3` but after change Android Studio as `Canary Build` the error gone

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simpe
just Locate **build.gradle** and replace **jcenter()** by **mavenCentral()**.

good luck

Answer (score -2):

The solution I did was to change build:gradle version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```