# Android studio couldn't load JitPack library

Tags: java, android

I am using one library from github to create a `tableview` but the `tableview` is showing an error in my project. I have added their implementation in my gradle file.

Library Link : https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

[image: XML code]

[image: Dependancies]

[image: Top level gradle file]

Answer (score 2):

JitPack seems to be published on `jcenter` whose use is [now deprecated in Android](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/). All non-Google artifacts now come from `mavenCentral`. The solution isn't documented in the official JitPack docs, but we can use the [`dependencyResolutionManagement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/resolve/DependencyResolutionManagement.html) block, like,

```
// settings.gradle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "App"
include ':app'
```

The code will enforce settings repositories on the repositories mentioned in `build.gradle`. For `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)` the [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration) say,

> If, for some reason, a project or a plugin declares a repository in a project, Gradle would warn you. You can however make it fail the build if you want to enforce that only settings repositories are used

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423513/13546426) answer along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330102/cannot-resolve-jitpack-dependencies-in-android-studio-in-the-last-gradle-version) one.